# Can both High poly model go with a low poly scene?

Tags: unity, art

I'm in the process of developing a game, and I've found a model that would go perfectly for the character. However, the scentre I already have is low poly and I can't find a good enough high poly to go with it. So tell me whether or not I should I should carry on with the art I have or find a low poly model.

Comment: You may generate a low polygon model from your high polygon one, or you could treat your low polygon enviroment as a place holder until you can work (or ge somebody to work) on a more polished one, or you could make a self-aware game where the characters mention how the world doesn't look realistic, or you can embrace it as an style choice that the less interative something is, the less realistic it looks...

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot you could by choosing the right material/texture that will give you that 'minimalistic look'. Like Theraot mentioned, there are ways to make your mesh low poly. Check out the script provided [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/798510/flat-shading.html) by the user 'robertbu'. It worked great for me and it might too for you!

Good luck,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

I know it's and old question, but for everyone who finds this question.

)One option as mentioned by the other answer is using a low-poly shader to emulate the low poly look with a high poly model. This doesn't actually reduce the polygons, but just makes the model look low-poly. If you are using the low poly style because you have extremely low specs like on an Oculus Quest 1 this will be a problem. There is even an unity asset to bake it into the model and texture without actually needing to use a shader.

> https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/lowpoly-shader-197219
> https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/lowpoly-mesh-generator-196511

)Use blender or some other modelling software to reduce the poygons of the model so much so much that it becomes low-poly style. I don't know much about modelling but the `Decimate modifier` in blender seems to make a mesh low-poly.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrD71-wXrIA

)As for characters you can look at anime games. Anime style characters are used with many different environment styles. For eg. realistic, stylized and I assume low-poly wouldn't look out of place either. You can use these games as reference for mixing styles. The humanoid characters are mostly anime and the enemies could be anything.
But you have to keep consistency unless you want your game to be called an asset flip. All humanoid characters be one style and the environments to be one style and the non-humanoid ones match the environment or character style.
Mixing and matching too much is gonna be a deal breaker for many players.

And slightly offtopic if you want to make all your characters Anime then you can use the free Anime Character creator calle VRoid Studio. You can just set some sliders and vallah! you have an anime character. And as for the clothes, some clothes are available for free and some others are sold cheaply on booth.pm . One just needs to select the clothes and they are applied. No 3d modeling skills needed.

> https://vroid.com/en/studio

Comment: It's unclear who you're quoting in these block quotes. This answer would be more actionable if it provided sample code/step by step guides to perform these solutions, rather than only asserting they're possible.

Comment: @DMGregory Added some more info and links.